# Django view function not being called

Tags: python, django, function, view

Ths is the function in question. The problem is that it does not seem to do be called. User can download any files on the server, regardless of whether `pk` matches `request.user.id` or not.

```
def permit(request, pk):
   # First I sanitize system_path from request, then...

   if int(request.user.id) == int(pk) and int(request.user.id) >= 1:
        sendfile(request, system_path)
   else:
        return render_to_response('forbidden.html')
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/notendur/list')
```

As you can see, it takes `pk` and compares it to `request.user.id`, and serves the file if that is the case.

Then the relevant bits of `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    #upload urls
    (r'^notendur/', include('notendur.urls')),

    #This needs to be changed to welcome.html
    (r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/notendur/list/')), # Just for ease of use.   

    #security
    url(r'^media/uploads/(?P<pk>[^/]+)', 'notendur.views.permit'),
    url(r'^media', 'notendur.views.permit'),
)
```

This error sort of came out of the blue. I hadn't edited anything pertaining to this as far as I am aware.

I know the function is not being called because I commented out the `sendfile()` and put `render_to_response('forbidden.html')` instead. Did not have any effect; user could still download file unexamined.

Comment: Append return statement just before sendfile execution.

Comment: Good catch, but I suppose that was a leftover from experimenting with render_to_response('forbidden.html'). The problem remains.

Comment: What is the actual you are trying to access this URL from ?

Comment: The actual what? If you mean where the urls.py file gets it from, it's a simple HTML link on the page.

Comment: Sorry.. the actual URL - 127.0.0.1:8000/....

Comment: For example: http://localhost/media/uploads/1/2014-06-24/envvars